# PostgreSQL - what do tms and mt mean in a SELECT query?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, query-performance

I'm trying to see if I can optimize the following query which was written by my predecessor:

```
   SELECT tms.*, 
          0 as kyori ,
          (power(
              (139.745069 - to_number(tms.lng,'000D00000000')) / 0.0111 * 1000000, 
              2) + 
           power(
              (35.662978 - to_number(tms.lat,'000D00000000')) / 0.0091   *1000000, 
              2)
          ) AS kyori2 
  FROM ttb_members tms, 
       mtb_tenshu mt 
  WHERE (tms.tenshu_cd = mt.small_cd) 
   AND (tms.view <> 0) 
   AND (tms.type in (2,3)) 
   AND (tms.delete_datetime is null)  
  ORDER BY kyori2 ASC 
  OFFSET 20 LIMIT 20
```

and I can't find any reference to the `tms.*` listed in the very beginning. The query seems to run if I remove it so I can't figure out exactly why it's there. Further, later in the query in the `FROM` line, there is `mtb_tensyu mt` which I can't get what the `mt` is. (For the record, 'kyori' in Japanese means 'distance').

I've Googled this and looked thoroughly at the PostgreSQL documents, but I can't find what these are referencing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry - I didn't know what it meant and I thought I could turn to this site for educating myself. After several Google searches I never found references to aliases. I am really grateful to Craig Ringer for helping me, though. Didn't mean to offend anyone.

Comment: I edited the question because (ironically) I was warned deleting it would deprive someone else of the knowledge from an answer. Hopefully this will put me back in good standing. Sorry for the mix-up.

Comment: For future reference: the relevant chapter in the manual is in "Chapter 7 - Queries". In there it's in the section "Select lists/Column labels": http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-COLUMN-LABELS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are table aliases.

See, later in the query:

```
FROM ttb_members tms
```

this is an *alias*, declaring that you intend to reference the table `ttb_members` as `tms` in the query. Aliases are useful for abbreviation and for when you want to reference one table multiple times in a query.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was something like that but I didn't find it in the docs. My bad.